How to actually use cv2.estimateAffine3D to align 3d points in python?
I want to compute a similarity alignment that overlays two sets of points in correspondence (rotation, scaling, translation). OpenCV has a lovely function for doing this, estimateAffine3D(). Despite a couple of other stack overflow questions about it, noone has presented an actual example of how to use this function to do what it is advertised to do (even the function documentation is opaque). Asking and answering my own question with a code example, just to get this documented and save you some time.

def similarity_align(v_src, v_target, v_transform=None):
    """
    find a similarity transformation that best maps v_src to v_target
    (points are in correspondence by index).
    v_src and v_target are numpy arrays of 3d points by row.
    Returns numpy array of transformed points v_transform if given,
    else transformed v_src
    """
    xform, scale = cv2.estimateAffine3D(v_src, v_target, force_rotation=True)
    src = v_src if v_transform is None else v_transform
    aligned = src.dot(xform[:, :3].T) * scale + xform[:, 3]
    return aligned


that doesn't do much beyond call the function. "xform" is a transformation matrix. you can apply it to points using cv.transform(). no need for what you're doing there (taking the matrix apart and applying it in parts).
